# Where can I find Thane?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After having EDI get settled in her new body, I just got an e-mail from Thane stating that he would be at the Huerta Hospital under an assumed name and encouraged me to visit him before his disease takes a hold of him.  However, going right to the hospital, I can find and talk to the Virmire survivor, but I cannot find Thane at all.

Is there a certain point in the game after I receive this e-mail that I can find him or am I missing an obvious door in the hospital?  I also searched the rest of the Citadel and could not find him.

The e-mail is as follows:

> Shepard,
>
> I've called and I've sent messages, but gotten no response.  With Earth's comm system out, I don't expect this will get through, either, but I heard a rumor the Normandy docked here at **the Citadel**.
>
> Are you alive?  **I'm at Huerta Memorial Hospital** under the name **Tannor Nuara**.  Please excuse the moniker and this email's encryption--in my line of work, it iss unwise to advertise my location, particularly when I am not in good health.
>
> We should meet before circumstances force us to part again.
>
> Thane

Emphasis mine.

Comment: i read the email but he never showed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video shows you where he is:

Note, Thane will not be there for your first hospital visit with Ash/Kaidan (when you go see them and Udina is there).

[Thane video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3X7eWHm8vA)

Look at L[essPop's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54675/where-can-i-find-thane/54679#54679) for the word description.

Comment: That would explain why i didn't see him the first time.

Comment: The video is unavailable and the current wording on this answer seems to rely on seeing what's in it so currently the answer makes no sense. i suggest at the adding in text where Thane is

Answer (score 5):

He's just inside the entrance, on the left, looking out the window.

Answer (score 1):

Thane is in Huerta memorial hospital.  Immediately after walking in, he's on the left near the window

Answer (score -2):

Thane should be in the Huerta Memorial Hospital  left side but i haven't played mass effect 3 where i can find him  again i just started from mass effect 1 to mass effect 3 with some mild dlc's included XD this time around i just looked at all the people giveing  answers  i thought i might put mine in as well hope it helps.

Comment: If other people have already answered a question, you shouldn't add another answer if you don't have anything different to contribute.

Comment: dont need to be rude i was trying to use a better explaination  than wat the other people were saying it didnt make any sense to me so did it better so no need to be rude okay?